# Clip Raster by Mask Layer - Nodata output

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, polygon, clip

I am trying to clip a raster around a polygon shapefile. I have managed to do it for a series of polygons with the same raster, however one polygon is returning a blank clipping with 'nodata' in each of the raster's bands.

I am working in EPSG:32755 coordinates and have checked previous posts but don't think it applies to my problem. The output raster is blank and has geometry outside the bounds of the above polygon.

Is the problem that the shapefile is too large to process? Each pixel contains 365 bands containing rainfall data from each day of the year for that area.

Edit: I have split the polygon into smaller pieces and the raster seems to be clipping to the mask fine, so how do I handle a larger polygon with more data?

[image]

Comment: It could be that the polygon has a geometry error. Try the `topology checker` and `check validity` tools.